# ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 1 - DataAnnotation Validation with complex model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-validation

The ability to let the model handle its own validation has lead me to begin playing with the MVC 2 preview release.  So far, I like the simplicity of the validation scheme.  However, I have run into a roadblock.  This validation style works fine for simple view model objects.  For example if I have a model object named **car** and I'm looking to create a view to create a new car:

-----Model-------

```
public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

-----Controller---------

```
public class CarController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        return View("Create", myCar);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Car myCar)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Create", myCar);
        }

        //Do something on success
        return View("Index");

    }

}
```

-------View--------------

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Car>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

    <% 
        using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit User Profile</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="Id">Id:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Id", Model.Id)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Id") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Name", Model.Name)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Color">Color:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Color", Model.Color)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Color") %>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

This works like a charm.  But not all of my views, or model objects for that matter, are simple.  I might have a car model object like:

-----Model-------

```
public class PaintScheme
{
    public int Red { get; set; }
    public int Blue { get; set; }
    public int Green { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PaintScheme Paint{ get; set; }
}
```

-------View--------------

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Car>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

    <% 
        using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit User Profile</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="Id">Id:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Id", Model.Id)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Id") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Name", Model.Name)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Red">Color Red:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Red", Model.Paint.Red)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Red") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Blue">Color Blue:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Blue", Model.Paint.Blue)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Blue") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Green">Color Green:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Green", Model.Paint.Green)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Green") %>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

When I add the **PaintScheme** properties to my view, they are not carried over with the "myCar" object passed into my controller action.  Is there a way to resolve this without having to rebuild the object from a form collection and then checking the ModelState?

Comment: I think the Title should be changed to something like "ASP.NET MVC Binding Nested Object Properties" as it doesn't seem to be related to DataAnnotations at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should have the **public setter** for properties you want to be bound. 
   I wonder how the first sample works for you as everything is private.
2. You have to **post at least one value** of PaintScheme property to be able to bind it.
3. All child properties should be prefixed with the **path** to it. Where *path* can be defined as *(PropertyName.)**.

It seems the point 3 is not satisfied in the View. Change the appropriate part of the view to this:

```
        <p>
            <label for="Red">Color Red:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Paint.Red")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Red") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Blue">Color Blue:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Paint.Blue")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Blue") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Green">Color Green:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Paint.Green")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Green") %>
        </p>
```

Additionally note that I removed explicit values from the TextBox helper to avoid possible NullReferenceException.

Comment: He left those out for brevity.

Comment: Ok. I think I see what's wrong. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing.  Thanks Dmitriy.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with this is to flatten your model using a dto. Then use automapper to map your domain object to your view model. This translation could be defined in such a way that you convert the enum to a string and back. Then validation will work and your bom won't touch the view maintaining your seperation of concerns fairly well.

Comment: Why to flatten and introduce another dependency instead of just *correctly* using the feature (ModelBinding)?  The model shown is not any complex to split it.

Comment: Maintaining a seperation of concerns from layer to layer will almost always make things cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

For the color part you can have something like this,
being an int I dont think you will use a textbox but this will bind your red color (if the input value is a number)

```
 <p>
                <label for="Red">Color:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Red", Model.Paint.Red)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Red") %>
 </p>
```